# On A+ mode not accessible to single point focus using canon 5D Mark iii

Tags: canon, canon-5d-mark-iii

I’m using canon 5D Mark iii , when I select mode A+ then I’m not able to access single point AF

Answer (score 2):

A+ mode gives all control over to the camera... if you want control over something like focus point selection, then you need to use a different mode.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting A+ mode tells the camera you want it to pick the AF mode and the AF point.

If you want to select the AF mode and/or AF point you can't use A+ mode.

Try P (Program) mode instead. It's the most automatic mode that lets you select things such as ISO, AF mode, etc. You can still set ISO to "Auto" in P mode if you want.